# Pyodide html вызов python Функции

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.23.3/full/pyodide.js"></script>
```

'''Как я понял, для работы нужно в голове укзать данную ссылку'''

```
    <h1>Создание обьявления</h1>

    <div class="group">         
        <label>Имя:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputValue1">
    </div>  

    <div class="group">
        <label>Номер телефона:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputValue2" placeholder="+7 000-000-00-00">
    </div>  

    <div class="group">
        <label>Текст:</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputValue3">
    </div>  

    <div>
        <center>
            <button type="button" onClick="myFunction()">
            Создать обьявление
            </button>
        </center>
    </div>
```

'''скрипт'''

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="create_obive.py"> 
    function myFunction() {
        var name = document.getElementById("inputValue1").value;
        alert(name)

        var text = document.getElementById("inputValue3").value;
        var nomer = document.getElementById("inputValue2").value;

        let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
```

'''будет работать? Какие то ошибки есть?'''

```
        pyodide.runPython(`
        create_obivlenie('${name}', '${text}', '${nomer}')
        `);}
        main();
    </script>

</form>
```

Comment: Ну запустите и посмотрите, будет ли работать и сыпет ли ошибками